# Compare two objects in an array, delete the duplicate data, and combine the different data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I am getting a list of objects in an array, some of which are duplicates. However, the condition that produces the duplicates is different.

So picture an array:

```
var array = [{id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'left'},
            {id: 2, name: 'example', condition: 'left'},
            {id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'right'},
            {id: 3, name: 'foobar', condition: 'right'}]
```

What I am looking for:

```
var solution = [{id: 1, name: 'test', condition: ['left', 'right']},
                {id: 2, name: 'example', condition: 'left'},
                {id: 3, name: 'foobar', condition: 'right'}]
```

I am able to delete duplicates no problem using this method:

```
var available = result.reduce((unique, o) => {
  if (!unique.some((obj) => obj.id === o.id && obj.name === o.name)) {
    unique.push(o);
  }
  return unique;
}, []);
```

But would Like to combine the condition data

Comment: So you want a difference?

Comment: Well I want to be able to keep the differences when I'm finding duplicates and maintain them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all with an object with combined keys.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'left' }, { id: 2, name: 'example', condition: 'left' }, { id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'right' }, { id: 3, name: 'foobar', condition: 'right' }],
    keys = ['id', 'name'],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        if (r[key]) r[key].condition = [].concat(r[key].condition, o.condition);
        else r[key] = { ...o };
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The .join in this solution changes the object data

Comment: the only join creates a key for the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in two steps.

1. Group the data by the id
2. Merge values for each group by combining the values of their properties

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1 , name: 'test'    , condition: 'left'  },
  { id: 2 , name: 'example' , condition: 'left'  },
  { id: 1 , name: 'test'    , condition: 'right' },
  { id: 3 , name: 'foobar'  , condition: 'right' }
];

const groupBy = (key, objs) => objs.reduce((acc, obj) =>
  ({ ...acc, [obj[key]]: [...(acc[obj[key]] || []), obj] }), {});

const combine = (newVal, oldVal) =>
 oldVal != null
  ? Array.isArray(oldVal)
    ? !oldVal.includes(newVal)
      ? [ ...oldVal, newVal ]
      : oldVal
    : oldVal !== newVal
      ? [ oldVal, newVal ]
      : oldVal
  : newVal;

const merge = (objs) => objs.reduce((acc, obj) =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc1, key) =>
    ({ ...acc1, [key]: combine(obj[key], acc1[key]) }), acc), {});

const groupByAndMerge = (key, items) =>
  Object.values(groupBy(key, items)).map(merge);

console.log(groupByAndMerge('id', array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Code golf

I reduced the function to a single-line statement with a size of 259 bytes.

```js
// Size: 259 bytes
f=(k,a)=>Object.values(a.reduce((r,i)=>({...r,[i[k]]:[...(r[i[k]]||[]),i]}),{})).map(g=>g.reduce((s,o)=>Object.keys(o).reduce((t,m)=>({...t,[m]:t[m]!=null?Array.isArray(t[m])?!t[m].includes(o[m])?[...t[m],o[m]]:t[m]:t[m]!==o[m]?[t[m],o[m]]:t[m]:o[m]}),s),{}))

console.log(f('id',[{id:1,name:'test',condition:'left'},{id:2,name:'example',condition:'left'},{id:1,name:'test',condition:'right'},{id:3,name:'foobar',condition:'right'}]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise solution with 4 steps that only checks for unique `ID`s:

1. find the unique `ID`s
2. for each unique `ID`, find the values of that `ID`
3. for each group of values with the same `ID`, find the unique `condition`s
4. for each group of values with the same `ID`, create 1 output value with the unique `ID`, `name`, and `condition`s

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'left'},
            {id: 2, name: 'example', condition: 'left'},
            {id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'right'},
            {id: 3, name: 'foobar', condition: 'right'}];

let groupedById = [...new Set(array.map(v => v.id))]
  .map(id => {
    let valuesWithId = array.filter(v => v.id === id);
    let condition = [...new Set(valuesWithId.map(v => v.condition))];
    return { ...valuesWithId[0], condition};
  });

console.log(groupedById);
```

If you really have data that has values of the same `ID` but different `name`s, this can be expanded to:

1. Iterate the input array, and for each value:
2. If it has an unseen `ID` & `name` combination, add it to the output (after transforming `condition` to an array).

3. If it has a seen `ID` & `name` combination, add it's `condition` to its existing counterpart (if it's not present already).

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'left'},
            {id: 2, name: 'example', condition: 'left'},
            {id: 1, name: 'test', condition: 'right'},
            {id: 3, name: 'foobar', condition: 'right'}];

let groupedByIdAndName = [];
array.forEach(value => {
  let duplicate = groupedByIdAndName.find(v => v.id === value.id && v.name === value.name);
  if (!duplicate)
    groupedByIdAndName.push({...value, condition: [value.condition]});   
  else if (duplicate.condition.every(c => c !== value.condition))
    duplicate.condition.push(value.condition);  
});

console.log(groupedByIdAndName);
```